# One Desktop, Four Clients Without Any Thin Client?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, thin-client

The videos below appear to have connected all monitors in to a single desktop without any thin clients in between. It looks like he installed 4 video cards in the desktop. It also looks like they have their own separate audio as if there was a client in between but there's none.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYqrDHJz80E

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBPv-kKLXTc

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCGQD7YinDg

The place appears to be a low-end internet cafe but it looks like he's saving a lot of energy in this setup. Any ideas how did he achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe he is using this software:

http://www.thincomputinginc.com/product_pc_sharing_betwin.aspx

Basically, what you mention (different video cards) and audio for each one comes from USB ports.